# Error al compilar proyecto OpenGL

Tags: c++, compilar, makefile

Estaba programando un proyecto en C++ con OpenGL que funcionaba antes de que tuviese que reinstalar Ubuntu. Depues de volver a instalar Ubuntu intalé las librerías mediante las siguientes ordenes en la terminal:

> sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install binutils-gold

Mi problema surge cuando al hacer make me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
ejecutando  prac  ....
./prac
make[1]: execvp: ./prac: Permiso denegado
makefile:47: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'exec'
make[1]: *** [exec] Error 127
makefile:44: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'start'
make: *** [start] Error 2
```

¿A que se debe este error y como puedo solucionarlo para poder compilar correctamente mi proyecto?

Comment: Estás segura de que prac tiene permisos de ejecución? Si no prueba chmod u+x prac

Comment: @Javier Ya lo resolví haciendo `make clean` y después `make` de nuevo. Creo que el problema estaba en que en la anterior compilación, en la anterior instalación de Ubuntu, se compiló con un compilador de 64 bits, y el compilador que tenía ahora instalado era 38 bits.